# Spring boot logback.xml externalisation

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, logging, logback

I am creating a Spring-boot application in which I would like to externalise the logback file. Reason I am doing this is to provide the flexibility of the consumer to decide in which location they would get the logs for the API. In order to achieve this I have added logging.config entry in my application.properties as below

```
logging.config=file:${CONFIG_HOME}apilogback.xml
```

CONFIG_HOME would be a environment variable that points to a common location for all the configuration files. Sample value given to **CONFIG_HOME** is **C:/SWS/apache-tomcat-8.5.16/appconfig/**
When I am running my API using tomcat rather than picking up the value of logging.config mentioned in the application.properties file it is picking up the default value defined in catalina.bat.
Default value in catalina.bat is as follows :

```
LOGGING_CONFIG=-Djava.util.logging.config.file="%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties"
```

To my surprise this seems to be working fine while running in a unix environment but not in a windows environment.
Is there a way to make sure we are loading value of logging.config from application.properties of my API.

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the environment variable `LOGGING_CONFIG` effectively overrides the value in `application.properties` (cf. [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)). All you can do is to set the value in a source with higher priority, e.g. as system property:

```java
try {
    if (System.getProperty("logging.config") == null) {
        final String config_home = System.getenv("CONFIG_HOME");
        if (config_home != null) {
            System.setProperty("logging.config", "file://" + configHome + "/apilogback.xml");
        }
    }
} catch (AccessControlException ex) {
    // SecurityManager in place...
}
```

However the name clash between the environment variable used by `catalina.sh/catalina.bat` and Spring has already been corrected in recent versions of Tomcat ([8.5.54](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_8.5.54_(markt)) and [9.0.34](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_9.0.34_(markt))), where the variable was renamed `CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG`.

The problem affects only Windows (and **only** if you use `catalina.bat/startup.bat`, running Tomcat as a service through *procrun* is not affected), because batch files don't have a concept of *local* environment variables:

```
set LOGGING_CONFIG=foobar
```

on Windows exports the environment variable to all children processes. On UNIX:

```
LOGGING_CONFIG=foobar
```

is available only to the current shell, if you want to export it to children processes (and those created using `exec`) you must use:

```
export LOGGING_CONFIG
```

**Remark:** You should call the environment variable in a different way, e.g. `<your application's name>_CONFIG_HOME>` so that you are sure you don't overwrite a variable used by another application. Better even, use a Spring configuration property, so you'll be able to set `CONFIG_HOME` in more than one way.

Comment: I was using tomcat 8.5.16 in my machine, after reading your response I switched to tomcat 8.5.54 and it's working fine. I been trying to figure out the issue for almost 2 days. Thanks a lot for the solution.